# How to code for non-repeating authentication strings

Tags: kali-linux

In THC Hydra, when you put the URL, form parameters, and condition (authentication) string:

`<URL>:<form parameters>:<condition strings>`

If you want Hydra to stop when it's successful you put `S=`
If you want it to stop when it fails, you put `F=`

The only explanations/tutorials I can find explain how to code in a repeating condition (authentication) string, i.e. Successful Login

`S=Successful Login`

What I need to know is how to code for a non-repeating condition (authentication) string, i.e. authlink=

my attempt:

`S=authlink=-x 6:6:aA1`

Comment: if no one here knows, do they at least know where i could ask?